# Significance of Number of Calls and Reset Call in Ball Tree

Tags: scikit-learn

Why does the Scikit Implementation has functions to reset and get number of calls?

How are these parameter important in Trees?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.reset_n_calls

Comment: Thank you for posting this query. Any chance you can give an example of what you are asking?

Comment: Its pretty straightforward. I was reading the docs (link in question) for sklearn implementation of Ball Tree and found a method which resets number of calls. But I dont know what does that mean. @shepan6

Comment: cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62731379/10495893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, they don't seem to be used for anything.  Probably they were included for some initial debugging?

An issue (and a linked PR) discussing these methods:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13330

(At time of posting,) searching for `n_calls` only finds results in `_binary_tree.pxi`, and none of them seem actually used for anything other than tracking the number of distances computed:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/search?q=n_calls

Comment: I see. Scikit documentation can be sometimes incomplete. Thanks